# the meaning of 'Held:'

Tags: legal-terms

I want to know the meaning of 'held:' in the middle of the image I attached below. It's very simple question but I'm an English learner. Please give me your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A [holding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holding_(law)) is effectively the outcome of a hearing, based on the relevant laws of the jurisdiction and the facts of the case.

The use of *held:* here indicates what that holding was.